# ActiveAdmin "has_many" form duplicates when I use "active_admin/select2"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2

When I use active_admin/select2 in my active_admin.js file, has_many form duplicates
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10tMo.png) , any ideas what`s going on with javascript? When I comment active_admin/select2 line, duplication is gone, but selector does not working anymore.

app/admin/user.rb

```
f.inputs do
  f.has_many :team_members, allow_destroy: true do |a|
    a.input :first_name
    a.input :last_name
    a.input :email
    a.input :groups, as: :select, collection: a.object.groups_for_select, multiple: true, include_hidden: false, input_html: { class: 'groups' }
    a.input :manager
  end
end
```

javascript/application.js

```
//= require select2
```

vendor/active_admin.js

```
//= require jquery.js
//= require active_admin/base
//= require active_admin/select2
```

Comment: Perhaps a context is missing? Could we have a link to the global project you are asking about, or a code that is reproducible on our own servers?

Comment: @AnthonyB No, sorry, I can't show you because project is on close github repository.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue with a bare rails application?

Comment: Guys thanks, but I found solution before I can recreate this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here [answer](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2267), I actually rename my active_admin.js to active_admin.js.erb and added next code.

```
<%
  require_asset "active_admin/select2.js"
  require_asset "active_admin/base"
%>
```

Now it's look like this and working perfectly for me. Duplication is gone.

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require active_admin/select2

<%
  require_asset "active_admin/select2.js"
  require_asset "active_admin/base"
%>

# Other js code...
```